# w3m causes question mark in html?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying this another time, hopefully with more details.

So i use phantomjs to read the source code of a website which is almost completely dynamic generated, and w3m to get it formatted. It would look like this

```
    exec('phantomjs sp.js http://randomwebsite.com > output.html ;w3m -dump output.html > formatted.txt);
```

After filtering out the Code block that i want which would look like this:

```
AS Monaco         Bayer Leverkusen
Borussia Dortmund Real Madrid
Dinamo Zagreb     Juventus Turin
FC Kopenhagen     FC Brügge
FC Sevilla        Olympique Lyon
Leicester City    FC Porto
```

I use htmlentities on this and get

```
AS Monaco         Bayer Leverkusen
Borussia Dortmund Real Madrid
Dinamo Zagreb     Juventus Turin
FC Kopenhagen     FC Br&uuml;gge
FC Sevilla        Olympique Lyon
Leicester City    FC Porto
```

which is completely what i want.
 This function shall return this exact output when i call it in html, but it just doesn't... i get all question marks for every special character and i just don't know why. A friend told me to look into w3m but couldn't really help me out too.

Edit: I just tested the coding type and get all ASCII  after i used htmlentities

```
AS Monaco         Bayer Leverkusen
ASCII         ASCII
Borussia Dortmund Real Madrid
ASCII         ASCII
Dinamo Zagreb     Juventus Turin
ASCII         ASCII
FC Kopenhagen     FC Br&uuml;gge
ASCII         ASCII
FC Sevilla        Olympique Lyon
ASCII         ASCII
Leicester City    FC Porto
ASCII         ASCII
```

in html i use utf8 like

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>.
```

I also just tried

```
$string = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
```

or

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
```

but it still remains the same

Comment: if you get `?` or blocks or other wonky chars instead of what you expect, then you almost certainly have a charset mismatch somewhere. every stage of your pipeline has to be using/expecting the same charset, or have appropriate translation logic at the "borders".

Comment: edited the question